# Maven Could not resolve dependencies

Tags: maven, dependencies

Now, i have a project which runs fine on my windows computer. But after I copied it to a linux computer, when compiling it reports following error:

Failed to execute goal on project alert: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.cloud.ras:alert.

The POM for com.external:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4.1 is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for com.external:freemarker:jar:2.3.4 is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for com.external:log4j:jar:1.2.14 is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for com.soa.lib:eBoxServiceCommon:jar:2.5.3 is missing, no dependency information available

but i have copied these jars to the maven repository. And can anyone give me a help?

Comment: If you (seem to) know the versions of external dependencies such as `commons-logging`, why don't you just depend on them; now it seems that you introduced a fake `groupId` of `com.external`, or do I see that wrong? What do you mean by "copied ... to ... repository"? Do you have a company repository, is it configured in your POM or in the `settings.xml` of the Linux box? Or did you refer to your local repository, not impossible, but hairy?

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT copy JARs in the first place. That's Maven job to resolve the dependencies for you.

It would be helpful if you explain the reason why you need to use your own `groupId` e.g. `com.external` in the first place i.e. `commons-logging` is from Apache but you use `com.external` as its `groupId`.

If you really insist on wanting to use your own `groupId`, at least download the JAR and install it using Maven. See here:
http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html.

Comment: Wanna upvote for hitting the original poster with some sense :) Wanna downvote for this not really answering much of a question :)

Comment: well, i have resolved this issue. The problem is that when compiling the project on my windows computer, it uses some repositories that have been downloaded to my local repository. If I cleaned the local repository and compiled the project again, it would failed, too. But, when i compiled it on my linux computer, because of no related repository in local repository, then it failed. At last, the root cause is that the pom file is not correct.